# How to alias union of three sets?

Tags: sql-server

I need alias union of three query like this:

```
select * from
(
select * from A
union
select * from B
union
select * from c)t1
```

My code appear error.

I don't know how solve it.

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of using SELECT *, specifically name your columns; that's probably where your error lies.  One or more of your tables (A, B, or C) probably has more or less columns than the others.

```
SELECT  col1, col2
FROM    ( SELECT    col1, col2
          FROM      A
          UNION
          SELECT    col1, col2
          FROM      B
          UNION
          SELECT    col1, col2
          FROM      c
        ) t1
```

If that doesn't fix it, then post the error message you received, and the RDBMS you are using.